# How to get refrence to scene component in Unreal Engine 5 with c++

Tags: c++, game-development, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

Basically, i want a door to open in unreal engine 5 with c++. I downloaded a door mesh from Sketchfab but the pivot point was at the senter of the mesh, so i created a actor class and attached a Scene component to it and to the scene component i attached a mesh then i kinda moved the mesh so the pivot point of the scene component would be at the buttom left corner of the door mesh. i already setup a function in the character that will be executed when he is looking at the door and press on the e key I also setup a function in the scene component (OnInteract) that should rotate the door 90 degrees. the problem is that i need to call this function from the character class.

here is the code for the OnInteract function in the SceneComponent:

```
void UDoorSceneComponent::OnInteract()
{
    GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 15.0f, FColor::Yellow, TEXT("The function is called"));
    FRotator NewRotation = GetRelativeRotation();
    NewRotation.Yaw -= 90;
    SetRelativeRotation(NewRotation);
}
```

code for the Interact function in the character class:

```
void APlayerCharacter::Interact()
{
    FHitResult HitResult;

    //Makes an invisible line between the Start and End point
    FVector Start = FollowCamera->GetComponentLocation();
    FVector End = Start + FollowCamera->GetForwardVector() * InteractLengh;
    
    // if something is between the line then it stores the information in HitResult
    GetWorld()->LineTraceSingleByChannel(HitResult, Start, End, ECollisionChannel::ECC_Visibility);

    // Cast to Door. will return a nullptr if the object between Start and End wasnt the door
    ADoor1* DoorCast = Cast<ADoor1>(HitResult.GetActor());

    // if Door exists (not a nullptr) run the open door funcion
    if(DoorCast)
    {
        // Got the actor refrence
        AActor* Door1Act = UGameplayStatics::GetActorOfClass(GetWorld(), ADoor1::StaticClass());
        ADoor1* Door1Cast = Cast<ADoor1>(Door1Act);
        if(Door1Cast == nullptr)
        {
            GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 15.0f, FColor::Yellow, TEXT("nullptr"));
        }
        else
        {
            GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 15.0f, FColor::Yellow, TEXT("not nullptr"));
        }
    }


}
```

as you can see, i have tried to get a refrence to the door class but i dont know how can i execute the OnInteract function from here.. I realy tried looking this up on google and didnt really found something. I use manjaro linux as the operating system.
Im also new to Unreal Engine so please take it easy :) thanks

edit: I added some debug messages and added a bool named test in the door class (set to true by default) then in the Interact function in the character class i added an if statement if(Door1Cast->test) that if its true ill get a screen debug message and i runed the code and i did get the debug message. I think that if i can get a refrence to the DoorSceneComponent in the Door1 class. Any ideas how?

Comment: OnInteract seems like a callback function that needs to be called when Interact event will happen on the door. I am not familiar with UE but you somehow have to trigger this event on the door.

Comment: i do trigger the event the Interact function works, i just need to find a way to call the OnInteract function

Comment: Where do you trigger Interact? In the code you posted I don't see anything which points to Interact call.

Comment: this is the triger for the function  PlayerInputComponent->BindAction("Interact", IE_Pressed, this, &APlayerCharacter::Interact); but that wont call it, i did set up the call in unreal engines input settings

Comment: I don't know the class hierarchy here, but maybe you should start logging debug messages in Interact functions of different components. Since OnInteract is in UDoorSceneComponent, I thought Interact event should also be triggered in UDoorSceneComponent.

Comment: i did as you said and i added some debug messages, now i figured out that i need a refrence to the DoorSceneComponent in the Door1 class so then i can call the OnInteract function. thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, you are able to use `test` field in `Door` object.

Now you want to be able to use `SceneComponent` as well. So, you need to make it field.

In your `Door` class declare private:

```cpp
UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere)
USceneComponent* MySceneComponent
```

In constructor:

```cpp
MySceneComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<USceneComponent>("SceneComponent");
```

And create method `GetMySceneComponent()`, which returns the pointer to `MySceneComponent`.

After it, you can cast to your `Door` class, and call `GetMySceneComponent()` method to get scene component you need.

Comment: are you sure thats a UFUNCTION ? i think thats a UPROPERTY

Comment: Yes, ofc it should be UPROPERTY. My bad :)

Comment: oh and how to i create the GetMySceneComponent() method? something like: USceneComponent GetDoorScene();       and like                              
USceneComponent ADoor1::GetDoorScene()
{
 return *DoorScene;
}          because i get a compile error "Calling a private constructor of class 'USceneComponent'"

Comment: Yeah, your method could look like:
`USceneComponent* GetDoorScene();`
`ADoor1::GetDoorScene() { return DoorScene; }`
without * in c++ code, cuz your property is already a pointer